# How to create Python code to read data from Excel file and create XML files

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xml, lxml, xlrd

I need help with creation of Python code to Create XML's using data in an Excel sheet. I am not a Python expert. I tried to create a piece of code below. The code just reads data from Excel but I am not sure how to write a code to convert that into an XML format.

The column in the Excel represents XML tags and rows represent unique data points

The code needs to create multiple XML files using the data points in the Excel file

Please find the code below. I have tried multiple things but couldn't complete the code.

```
 import xlrd

 ExcelFileName= 'Data.xlsx'
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFileName)
 worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
 num_rows = worksheet.nrows
 num_cols = worksheet.ncols
 result_data = []

 for curr_row in range(0, num_rows, 1):
     row_data = []

     for curr_col in range(0, num_cols, 1):
         data = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)
         print(data)
         row_data.append(data)

     result_data.append(row_data)
```

Comment: Which row in the worksheet has the XML Tags. You say the "columns" represent the tags but where are they in the sheet, or is this just "tag_1", "tag_2" ... "tag_n".

Comment: Hey,apologies for the delayed response.It is just like tag_1,tag_2....tag_n as you are saying

Comment: Hey,apologies for multiple responses i was not able to edit the previous response.1st row has the Xml tags and  the next rows represents/contains the data corresponding to those tags.What i want to do is to create a python code which will read this excel and create xml's for each row of data

Answer (score 0):

It seems you know how to read excel file. Use ElementTree in python to write to xml.
Let's say you have an xml like

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="col1">row1</item>
        <item name="col2">row2</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

You can write this with following code 
s>

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# create the file structure
data = ET.Element('data')
items = ET.SubElement(data, 'items')
item1 = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
item2 = ET.SubElement(items, 'item')
item1.set('name','col1')
item2.set('name','col2')
item1.text = 'row1'
item2.text = 'row2'

# create a new XML file with the results
mydata = ET.tostring(data)
myfile = open("example.xml", "w")
myfile.write(mydata)
```

Comment: Not able to execute this code.I am not able to patch your code with mine, seems like some indentation issue, I tried multiple tools to fix the issue but it didn't work. Can you help with the same?

I will repeat my requirement again

1st row has the Xml tags and the next rows represents/contains the data corresponding to those tags.What i want to do is to create a python code which will read this excel and create xml's for each row of data

Comment: Hey agasthya,there is a indentation error in my code in line 8 and it is asking me to import xlrd package inspite of already importing it.                                                                                                       
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/satyawand/PycharmProjects/dacr/xml.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlrd
  File "C:\Users\satyawand\PycharmProjects\dacr\xlrd.py", line 8
    for curr_row in range(0, num_rows, 1):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent  
Note:- I am executing the code on pycharm with python interpreter 2.7

Comment: @Satya123 I think the range function only accepts two arguments. That might be the root cause of that error